# public function access fail

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have this situation where I declare inside my main class a function that looks like this:

```
public class Main extends MovieClip
{

    public static var instance:Main;

    public function Main()
    {
        // constructor code
        welcomeScreen();
        instance = this;
    }

    public final function welcomeScreen():void
    {
        //some code in here
    }

    public final function startLevelOne():void 
    {
        //some other code here
    }


}
```

In some other class I use this statement to fire a reset:

```
restart.addEventListener('click', function() {                                      
     Main.instance.welcomeScreen();
});
```

Somehow in another class I try to use the same statement for 'startLevelOne' but it seems it is not working and gives the fallowing error:

```
1195: Attempted access of inaccessible method startLevelOne through a reference with static type Main.
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE #1**

The class where I try to access the function is in full this one:

```
public class LevelBrief extends MovieClip
{

    public function LevelBrief()
    {
        // constructor code
        startBut.addEventListener('click', function() {
            Main.instance.startLevelOne();
        });
    }
}
```

**UPDATE #2**

I have pasted the full code of the main definition here http://pastebin.com/s6hGv7sT

Also the other class could be found here http://pastebin.com/s6h3Pwbp

**UPDATE #3**

Even though the problem was solved with a workaround, I still cannot understand where was the problem.

Comment: Can you attach the problematic code block (with `startLevelOne` call)?

Comment: Does `Main` implement an interface which declare `startLevelOne()`? Because the above code works well when compiled with Flash Builder...

Comment: what do you mean by "implement an interface"?

Comment: Something like `public class Main extends MovieClip implements GameController`. In my example if `GameController` declares `startLevelOne()` with different signature than `Main`, it will raise the same error. Since you _shadowed_ your code I can't do that much!

Comment: No, it does not implement any interface at all. Actually there is not much code yet, so what I have pasted here is pretty much the same that I got into my application :)

Comment: Here is a [working example](http://wonderfl.net/c/rCSE).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend to leave the static instance (singleton), and work event-based. Now you make all functions public, which is not desirable. It's not that hard to use custom events. See this is how your *Main* class could look:

```
public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    public function Main()
    {
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, handleAddedToStage);
    }

    public function handleAddedToStage(event:Event)
    {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, handleAddedToStage);

        this.showWelcomeScreen();

        stage.addEventListener(ScreenEvent.SHOW_WELCOME_SCREEN, handleScreenEvent);
        stage.addEventListener(ScreenEvent.SHOW_LEVEL, handleScreenEvent);
    }


    private function handleScreenEvent(event:ScreenEvent):void
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
            case ScreenEvent.SHOW_WELCOME_SCREEN:
            {
                this.showWelcomeScreen()
                break;
            }
            case ScreenEvent.SHOW_LEVEL:
            {
                // event.data contains level number
                this.startLevel(event.data);
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                trace("Main.handleScreenEvent :: Cannot find event.type '" + event.type + "'.");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private function showWelcomeScreen():void
    {
        trace("show WelcomeScreen")
        //some private code in here
    }

    private function startLevel(level:int):void 
    {
        trace("start level: " + level)
        //some other private code here
    }
}
```

This is how the custom event class should look (*ScreenEvent.as*). Note it has an optional parameter called *data*. You can pass any value (objects, numbers, strings etc) into this. To the example as clear as possible, I used one event-class for both actions, you can also choose to make more specific custom events for other actions with more detailed parameters, you would have names like *ScreenEvent*, *LevelEvent*, *PlayerEvent*, *GameEvent* etc etc..

At the top of the class the (static constant) types are defined. An event should only have getters.

```
package 
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class ScreenEvent extends Event
    {
        public static const SHOW_WELCOME_SCREEN:String = "ScreenEvent.showWelcomeScreen";
        // event.data contains level number
        public static const SHOW_LEVEL:String = "ScreenEvent.showLevel";

        private var _data:String;

        public function ScreenEvent(type:String, data:String):void 
        { 
            super(type);
            this._data = data;
        }

        public function get data():String
        {
            return this._data;
        }

        override public function clone():Event 
        { 
            return new ScreenEvent(this.type, this._data);
        }
    }
}
```

.. Anywhere in your code you can *dispatch* the event to the stage.

```
// dispatch event to Main (stage). Should show welcome screen in our case
stage.dispatchEvent(new ScreenEvent(ScreenEvent.SHOW_WELCOME_SCREEN));

// show level 2
stage.dispatchEvent(new ScreenEvent(ScreenEvent.SHOW_LEVEL, 2));
```

I know, its a bit more code, it looks more difficult at first but if the project grows, it will help a lot. The difference with events is '*this could happen, and when it happens, do this*' instead of '*do this here, do that over there*'
The advantage is that if you remove the event listener in the Main class, nothing will break (loosely coupled). This makes it easier to maintain, it saves a singleton, and you have the ability to extend the Main class *if* you want to.

Comment: This seems ok for me, only it is not working due to the fact that stage from the main class in null and pops out: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Comment: It works if you add a a function that will execute when added to stage since stage is null at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you wrote

```
Main.startLevelOne();
```

instead of

```
Main.instance.startLevelOne();
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. Given your code, there is only one serious question - what is PerwollGame? You have there `public static var instance:PerwollGame;` and you assign it an object of type Main. Perhaps that PerwollGame has a `startLevelOne()` function with a different signature, that obscures your function in the Main class. Also, the other people who answered you are right as well, you should never use nested functions in your code, really put that listener of yours out from inline declaration.

Comment: I corrected that so I use only Main, so it is not from there :)

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your coding style and the error reported, I would assume you did this.

```
public static function startLevelOne():void
```

There is a fine line between static methods and instantiated objects.

Also never use nested functions

```
public class LevelBrief extends MovieClip
{

    public function LevelBrief()
    {
        // constructor code
        startBut.addEventListener('click', onMyClick )
    }

    public functiononMyClick (e:Event) {
            Main.instance.startLevelOne();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: As you can see in my question the function declaration is "public final function" and not "public static function".

Answer (score 0):

I assume that when you register the listener Main.instance is not already assigned.
Did you try to trace Main instance here?

```
public function LevelBrief()
{
    // constructor code
    startBut.addEventListener('click', function() {
        Main.instance.startLevelOne();
    });
    trace(Main.instance); // I assume Main.instance is null
}
```

what about if you add the listener in another method in LevelBrief like :

```
public function registerListeners():void{
        trace("Main.instance == null? -> " + (Main.instance == null)); //not null here if called later.
        startBut.addEventListener('click', function() {
        Main.instance.startLevelOne();
        });
    }
```

Comment: The first method traces "[object Main]" so the instance object is not null.